# include character vector (listing function methods) in a package

Tags: r, package

I'm working on a package in which I need to include a character vector of the methods available for one of the functions - like the p.adjust.methods that are available for the p.adjust function in the stats package:

```
p.adjust(p, method = p.adjust.methods, n = length(p))

p.adjust.methods
# c("holm", "hochberg", "hommel", "bonferroni", "BH", "BY",
#   "fdr", "none")
```

However, if I include a vector similar to p.adjust.methods in my workspace (along with the functions) and run package.skeleton, the vector is saved as a data file, so then (after the package is installed and loaded in a clean workspace) it can't be accessed by the user or the functions unless they type 'data(xfunction.methods)' first.

How could I get character vectors included in my package the same way as p.adjust.methods is included in the stats package?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Place `p.adjust.methods <- c("one", "two", ...)` somewhere in your package's `R` folder and update the `NAMESPACE` file to contain `export(p.adjust.methods)`.

Comment: hm... the vector still doesn't get exported for some reason. Instead I wrote a function that returns the vector and included it in the package. Thanks, though!